# 'Add Foreign Key properties' for a One to Zero-to-one relationship

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity model which defines a One to Zero-to-one association between two entities. i.e.

```
A  [0..1]..[1]  B
A has one reference to B. B can have a reference to A.
```

In defining this association, I want to have the ID of 'B' within 'A'. e.g. a B_ID property. For some reason, the option to do so - 'Add foreign key properties to the 'A' entity' - is disabled. I don't know why this is, and I'm unable to figure out how to do it manually.

If anyone could help, or give me a reason for this, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Just to clarify you are using the designer (.EDMX file) and what version of EF 5.0?

Comment: I am using the designer, and the version - I think - is 2.0. (Judging from the EDMX root node - <edmx:Edmx Version="2.0"...)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following article describes what you are trying to do and how to do it:

http://www.develop-one.net/blog/2011/06/29/EntityFrameworkModelFirstOnetoOneRelationship.aspx

The bit you appear to be missing (from your description) is to modify the existing 1-* relationship rather than create a new one. I am assuming you are using the designer.

Comment: That looks like it's trying to emulate inheritance? This isn't a inheritance relationship - A 'has a' B. 'C' may also 'have a' B, if that makes sense, which is why it's a One-to-[0..1]. Basically EF seems to be doing everything correctly apart from giving me the foreign key property. The table for A has a 'B_ID' column, and the entity for A has a 'B' property, but not a 'B_ID' property. Thanks for your reply.